# Xamarin.Forms: ScrollView not scrolling on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, scrollview, xamarin.forms, windows-10-mobile

This code is working fine on iOS and Android, but not on a Windows 10 Mobile device (Microsoft Lumia 650, Version: 1511, Build: 10.0.10586.11):

```cs
public App()
{
    var layout = new StackLayout
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        Padding = 0,
        Children =
            {
                new Button { Text = "A" },
                new Button { Text = "B" },
                new Button { Text = "C" },
                new Button { Text = "D" },
                new Button { Text = "E" },
                new Button { Text = "F" },
                new Button { Text = "G" },
                new Button { Text = "H" },
                new Button { Text = "I" },
                new Button { Text = "J" },
                new Button { Text = "K" },
                new Button { Text = "L" },
                new Button { Text = "M" },
                new Button { Text = "N" },
                new Button { Text = "O" },
                new Button { Text = "P" },
                new Button { Text = "Q" },
                new Button { Text = "R" },
                new Button { Text = "S" },
                new Button { Text = "T" },
                new Button { Text = "U" },
                new Button { Text = "V" },
                new Button { Text = "W" },
                new Button { Text = "X" },
                new Button { Text = "Y" },
                new Button { Text = "Z" },
            },
    };
    var scrollView = new ScrollView { Content = layout };

    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new ContentPage
    {
        Content = scrollView,
    };
}
```

The scroll view is not scrolling at all. I can see the scrollbar, but it doesn't scroll. I tried to play with `HorizontalOptions`/`VerticalOptions`, but that didn't helped either. In the simulator it does work by scrolling with the mouse. The same problem also occurs with `Label`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: what version of `Xamarin.Forms` are you using? it could be a related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36173)

Comment: Perhaps related. Using Xamarin Forms 2.0 and UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been fixed in Xamarin Forms 2.1.0.